# Centering Semantic UI Column Contents

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

### issue

When the page is small, the profile picture is centered correctly. When the page is full sized, it floats to the left. Why is this?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Grid centered>
        <Container>
          <Image src={image} size="small" />
        </Container>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

### centered correctly

[image]

### floating left

[image]

### sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/w77kymo1lw

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ui centered image` to your image component.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Grid centered>
        <Container>
          <Image ui centered image src={image} size="small" />
        </Container>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you explain what the `ui` and `image` props do, please?